# Android:notification problem

Tags: android

I have an application that will clear the missed calls displayed on the status bar. I can clear it but when you restart the phone, the missed calls on the status bar is still there? How can I permanently remove it using my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot affect other applications' notifications in Android.